# What is the optimal way of printing a 2d array vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function which receive a 2D vector of char from another class and print it

```
void dat_Output::print_All(Board *board)
{
  int x;
  int y;

  x = 0;
  y = 0;                                    
  while(x < 26)
    {
      while(y < 59)
        {
          std::cout << board->get_Board()[x][y];
          y++;
        }
      std::cout << std::endl;
      y = 0;
      x++;
    }
}
```

here is the get_Board() function

```
std::vector<std::vector<char> > Board::get_Board()
{
  return(board);
}
```

My question is for resource efficiency which is the better should I make a copy of the vector at the start of my printing function to avoid calling get_Board() 26*59 time? and whats the difference on resource consuming?

Comment: Why `get_Board()` returns a copy ? Cant you return a reference ? Also, wht's goin on with those nested `while` loops ? Any reason for not doing `for` loops ?

Comment: @quantdev: Reference/copy depends on what semantics you're aiming for.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, definitely, this is why I'm asking the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If `get_Board()` **must** return a copy, make a single copy **before** the loops (instead of 26 * 59 copies), and work directly on it. It will also avoid you the `board->` indirection.
- If possible, return a const reference instead of a copy from `get_Board()`
- Assuming you want to print the entire board, don't use nested `while` loops, you can use nested `for-range` loops and avoid explicit indexing.

Minimal example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class X
{
    public :
        X() : v({ { 'a', 'b'} ,  { 'a', 'b' } , { 'c', 'd' } }) {}

    const std::vector<std::vector<char>> & GetVector() const { return v; }

    private:
        std::vector<std::vector<char> > v;
};


int main() {
    X x;

    const std::vector<std::vector<char> >& v = x.GetVector();

    for(auto& v2 : v)
      for(auto& c : v2)
        std::cout << c << ' ';
}
```

Comment: I get all but, what do u mean by explicit range ?

Comment: I meant that I didn't need your indexes `x` and `y`, they are implicit in those `for` loops

Answer (score 0):

```
void dat_Output::print_All(Board *board)
{
  std::vector<std::vector<char> > myboard = board->get_Board()[x][y];   
  int x;
  int y;

  x = 0;
  y = 0;                                    
  while(x < 26)
    {
      while(y < 59)
        {
          std::cout << myboard[x][y]; 
          y++;
        }
      std::cout << std::endl;
      y = 0;
      x++;
    }
}
```

I would create a copy initially. I think every time you call get_Board() you would return a array of vector of vectors and this would be hit on the performance, while calling it once would be cheaper.